# SCSS helper classes @mixin with dashes issue

Tags: css, sass

I'm building a bunch of my own helper classes and for most CSS properties/values they are one word so my SCSS code below works fine but for something like `justify-content: flex-start` I've hit the wall.

I was using `str-slice` to take the first letter from the property and value but now I need to extend that if the property value uses a dash.

Any thoughts?

```
$positions: ('relative', 'absolute', 'fixed', 'sticky');
$flexPositions: ('flex-start', 'center', 'flex-end');
@mixin positionHelpers($breakpoint) {
    @each $position in $positions {
        .p\:#{str-slice($position, 0, 1)}\@#{$breakpoint} {
            position: #{$position} !important;
        }
    }
    @each $position in $flexPositions {
        .jc\:#{str-slice($position, 0, 1)}\@#{$breakpoint} {
            justify-content: #{$position} !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Added the following for more context:

```
$defaultBreakpoints: (
    'xs': 'screen and (max-width: 767px)',
    'sm': 'screen and (min-width:768px)',
    'md': 'screen and (min-width:1024px)',
    'lg': 'screen and (min-width:1201px)'
);
@each $breakpoint, $query in $defaultBreakpoints {
    @if $breakpoint == 'xs' {
      @include positionHelpers(#{$breakpoint})
    } @else {
        @media #{$query} {
            @include positionHelpers(#{$breakpoint})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you want? What is `$breakpoint`?

Comment: `js:fs@xs` for example, or `js:fe@xs` – $breakpoints is an associative array of, for example, `'xs':'screen and (max-width: 767px)'` – I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to split your string in 2 parts when there is a dash `-` in it.

```
 @function split($string, $separator:"-") {
   $index : str-index($string,  $separator);
   $newString:"";

   @if($index!= null){
      $str-1 : #{str-slice(str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1), 0, 1)};
      $str-2 : #{str-slice(str-slice($string, $index + 1), 0, 1)};
      $newString: $str-1 + $str-2
   } @else{
     $newString: str-slice($string,  0, 1);
   }

   @return $newString;
}
```

Then you can call it in your `@each $position in $flexPositions {...}`:

```
$positions: ('relative', 'absolute', 'fixed', 'sticky');
$flexPositions: ('flex-start', 'center', 'flex-end');
@mixin positionHelpers($breakpoint) {
    @each $position in $positions {
        .p\:#{str-slice($position, 0, 1)}\@#{$breakpoint} {
            position: #{$position} !important;
        }
    }
    @each $position in $flexPositions {
        $string: split($position); /*here you create a new string*/
        .jc\:#{$string}\@#{$breakpoint} {
            justify-content: #{$position} !important;
        }
    }
}
```